# Drop rows randomly from a dataframe such that no rows exist with a count over N

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe `df` of encoded topics and items that looks like

```
topic    item
0        bucket
1        fish
2        car
0        pail
2        truck
3        glove
```

where there are `X` topics and `Y` items, such that if I look at a count of items per topic

```
print(df.groupby(by='topic').agg('count'))

                 item
topic                
0                8568   
1                7539  
2               48700   
3               26036   
4                4190  
5                2153 
...               ...
X-2               328
X-1              5942
X               15871
```

How could I make this such that no topic has no more than N associated items? For example, let's say `N = 5000`. Then, were I do a count I would get

```
print(df.groupby(by='topic').agg('count'))

                 item
topic                
0                5000   
1                5000  
2                5000   
3                5000   
4                4190  
5                2153 
...               ...
X-2               328
X-1              5000
X                5000
```

Where everything that has above 5000 counts is reduced to 5000 counts and everything below it is left untouched. The rows dropped also need to be dropped randomly, and not just the first appearing.

```
psuedocode:

# Randomly drops rows by topic until there are no topics that have a count
# above 5000
df.drop_rows_by_count(
                      based_on='topic'
                      above_below='above', 
                      count=5000,
                      how='random'
)
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You want to remove rows from the original dataframe so that there are no more than `n` instances per topic?

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do @HenryEcker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shuffle the entire dataframe first with `sample` and a `frac` argument of `1` (which basically "samples" the entire dataframe). The `replace=False` argument keeps pandas from selecting the same row twice during the sampling process.

Then use `head` to get the first N occurences (at random order since we just shuffled the rows):

```
df.sample(frac=1, replace=False).groupby('topic').head(5000)
```